# Как работать с таймером в СИ?

Tags: c, таймер

как  **правильно** пользоваться таймером в CИ ?

К примеру мне нужно подождать без "засыпания" 100 мс для последующей "работы", но при этом выполнять иные "задачи" пока жду завершения "поставленного" времени.

К примеру можно использовать `sleep(3)` НО он "уводит" процесс в "засыпание" и я не могу выполнять иные задачи во время "этого" промежутка времени.

---

*этот вопрос создал в связи с тем что, в книгах столкнулся с малым количеством примеров работы с таймером, (книги новые, Язык си в XXI веке и Язык С Справочник(стандарт С11) )*

Comment: Если не хотите углубляться в многопоточность, то можно попробовать сделать через `setitimer()` или `timer_settime()`. Можно и через `alarm()`, но там точность — секунда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в СИ можно использовать **стандартную библиотеку**, подключить заголовочный файл `time.h`

Можно использовать арифметический тип `clock_t` возвращаемый функцией `clock()`

Сохраняем стартовое время  в переменой `start` с помощью `clock()` и проверяем  прошедшее время, сравнивая разницу между сохраненным временем и текущим временем.

вот пример :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void ProcessIntenseFunction()
{
    for(int i =0; i<1000; i++){
    printf("ProcessIntenseFunction()\n");
    printf("ProcessIntenseFunction()\n");
    printf("ProcessIntenseFunction()\n");
    printf("ProcessIntenseFunction()\n");
    printf("ProcessIntenseFunction()\n");
    }

}

int main()
{

    clock_t start = clock(), diff; // Так  и не понял как работает и что это за зверь такой diff 
    ProcessIntenseFunction();
    diff = clock() - start;

    int msec1 = diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds", msec1/1000, msec1%1000);
    return 0;
}
```

*Увы с этим "зверем" я не совладал :(*

Сам на практике пользуюсь арифметическим типом `time_t` возвращаемый функцией `time()`   :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    int msec = 0, trigger = 10; /* 10ms */
    clock_t before = clock();
    int iterations = 0;

    do {
      //---  
      printf("Hello World!\n"); // вот этот код будет отрабатываться пока msec не станет больше trigger
      //---

      clock_t difference = clock() - before;
      msec = difference * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      iterations++;
    } while ( msec < trigger );

    printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds (%d iterations)\n",
      msec/1000, msec%1000, iterations);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `clock_t start = clock(), diff;` эквивалентно двум строкам: `clock_t start = clock();` и `clock_t diff;`. Это просто объявление двух переменных (`start` и `diff`) - одна с инициализацией, другая без.

Answer (score 1):

> мне нужно подождать 100 мс, но при этом выполнять иные задачи

Это называется "мультипрограммирование". Или, по другому "параллельное программирование" потому, что **несколько** "потоков управления" (программ, подпрограмм...) выполняются параллельно.

Независимо от языка программирования и ОС, для оторой Вы пытаетесь написать программу, есть всего две методики организации мультипрограммирования:

- Нити (треды - thread)
- Процессы

В разных ОС эти подходы реализуются чуть-чуть по разному. Если говорить о Linux, то:

- Нити реализуются с помощью библиотеки pthread (см. http://ccfit.nsu.ru/arom/data/PP_ICaG/03_pthreads_txt.pdf)
- Потоки создаются системным вызовом *fork()* (см. man 2 fork)

В любом случае, параллельное программирование - тема очень сложная и ребует время для освоения. Подумайте - никак не обойтись?